# Why does it show error when I put data types before variables inside the argument section in the user defined function of the following program

Tags: user-defined-functions

Why does it show error when I put data types before variables inside the argument section in the user defined function of the following program

```
main() {
  float a = 15.5;
  char ch = 'C';
  printit(a, ch);
}
printit(a, ch) {
  printf("\n%f %c", a, ch);
}
```

Comment: Which programming language is that?

Comment: which language is this? what error are you getting? If this is C/C++ you need to declare the function `printit` before you can consume it in main